# Query "select where" return no matched data in sqlite android

Tags: android, sqlite

i have a problem with query `select where` clause  in `sqlite`. When i try to match the data from `textView` with `database` it's return no matched data.

My query function

```
public void cekPosisi(String txtAlamat) {
    String add = "";
    String alarm = "";
    Cursor cur = db.rawQuery("select * from task_table where alamat = '" + 
            txtAlamat + "'", null);
    if(cur.moveToFirst()) {
        add = cur.getString(5);
        alarm = "Anda ada tugas di lokasi: " + add;
        for (; !cur.isAfterLast(); cur.moveToNext()) {
            add = cur.getString(5);
            alarm = "Anda ada tugas di lokasi: " + add;
        }
    }
    if(add.equals("")) {
        add = "Anda tidak ada tugas di lokasi sekarang";
        alarm = "" + add;
    }
    Toast.makeText(this, alarm, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Implemented in

```
//cek tugas
    this.cariTugas.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            txtAddr = teksAlamat.getText().toString();
            Log.d("alamat textView", txtAddr);
            cekPosisi(txtAddr);
        }
    });
```

In first code, it's alaways run to `if(add.equals(""))` condition so it will show "Anda tidak ada tugas di lokasi sekarang"...
Please any help. Thanks

Comment: [Occam's razor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occam's_razor) ... there is no data in database ... or teksAlamat contains spaces

Comment: Try `txtAlamat.trim()` in query

Comment: How many columns does `task_table` have?

Comment: you should use LIKE not "=" for string comparison

Comment: @Squonk it have 6 columns

Comment: @blackbelt, can you give an example... sorry, i confuse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use like below:

```
Cursor cur = db.rawQuery("select * from task_table where alamat = '%" + 
        txtAlamat + "%'", null);
```

check this [link](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp) there is example with LIKE Query. and hou use wildcards (missing letters in the pattern) in Query.

**Edited:**

```
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select * from task_table where alamat = '%" + 
            txtAlamat + "%'", null);
    if(cursor){
        Toast.makeText(this, "no data", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                      add = cur.getString(5);
                      if(!add.equalsIgnoreCase("")){
                         alarm = "Anda ada tugas di lokasi: " + add;
                      }else{
                         add = "Anda tidak ada tugas di lokasi sekarang";
                         alarm = "" + add;
                      }
                } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }
```

Comment: you have insert any data in your database??

Comment: when the Toast.makeText appear, it doesn't show anything.. Only little black box...

Answer (score 0):

```
//cek tugas
    this.cariTugas.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            txtAddr = teksAlamat.getText().toString().trim();
            Log.d("alamat textView", txtAddr);
            if(txtAddr != null && !txtAddr.equals("")){
                cekPosisi(txtAddr);
            }else{
                Log.d("","Please enter value again");
            }
          }
      });


//if you have data in the database then you will have values accordingly
```

Comment: It's still return nothing. I try to manual query with sqlite browser using "select *" and the result not empty